# Unclickable context menu inside content editable

Tags: html, css

I have a little issue with my context menu inside a content editable. I think it's a style issue but i can't figure out what it's causing it. Here is the thing, my context menu is showing where he is suposed to, with the value he is suposed to have. But it seems like it is only a block for him and not a list of P element Inside my DIV element.

[image]

As you can see we can't click on the element Inside the context Menu.

My CSS :

```
.ctxmenu
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    z-index: 11;
    overflow: visible;
}
.ctxline
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
    border: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
    overflow: visible;
}
.ctxline:hover
{
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

The content editable CSS :

```
.rootClass 
{
    border:1 solid buttonface; 
    border:2 groove buttonhighlight;
    OVERFLOW: scroll; 
    OVERFLOW-X: hidden; 
    OVERFLOW-Y: auto; 
    WIDTH: 762px; 
    POSITION: relative; 
    TOP: 65px; 
    left: 10px; 
    HEIGHT: 88%; 
    WORD-WRAP: break-word;
    FONT-FAMILY :Times New Roman;
    background-color: white;
}

.menu_editeur 
{   
    border : 0;
    background-color : #cccccc;
}
```

the HTML :

```
<DIV id=edth_corps contentEditable=true style="WORD-WRAP: break-word; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; BORDER-TOP: buttonhighlight 2px groove; HEIGHT: 400px; FONT-FAMILY: Helvetica; BORDER-RIGHT: buttonhighlight 2px groove; WIDTH: 690px; OVERFLOW-X: hidden; BORDER-BOTTOM: buttonhighlight 2px groove; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 10px; BORDER-LEFT: buttonhighlight 2px groove; Z-INDEX: 4; TOP: 132px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white" name="lettre" unselectable="" comportement="F">
    <P><SPAN id=0 class=erreurOrthographe oncontextmenu="rightClickMustWork(this);return false">tset</SPAN> pour <SPAN id=1 class=erreurOrthographe oncontextmenu="rightClickMustWork(this);return false">vior</SPAN>
        <DIV id=ctxmenu1 class=ctxmenu contentEditable=false style="CURSOR: pointer; LEFT: 59px; TOP: 15px">
            <P onclick=alertMe(); class=ctxline>viorne</P>
            <P onclick=alertMe(); class=ctxline>viornes</P>
        </DIV>
    </P>
</DIV>
```

Or if you know any properties that might end up doing this, my cowerker may have hide some CSS on other place (they did not use a CSS file to put all style inside ...).

Example of what he should do :

[image]

Comment: also add your HTML and a the end result you expect as a reference, please!

Comment: Updated with HTML and the result it should do (i can see that the ctxline:over is not taken, the HTML think the contextMenu is another contentEditable I think)

Comment: @Slayner would you mind to add your HTML in text?

Comment: @TonyWu well he is auto generated, so i can only look at it with F12, sorry (by the way it is in IE11)

Comment: @Slayner you could collapse the div tag and right click -> copy the html script in IE11 Developer Tools

Comment: @TonyWu it's done mate.

Comment: @Slayner Thank you so much. I will try.

Comment: I tried forcing the contentEditable on the context menu at false, but it did nothing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2wown2cr/

Comment: @Slayner add `readonly="readonly" disable`

Comment: i have to add it to the content div edth_corps ? because i can't really touch this part. (the ctxmenu is generated by javascript so how do i had the disable at the end for him ?). And by the way readOnly may prevent my click event to work on the contextMenu.

Comment: @TonyWu your solution can't be applied, disable prevent my action from execution on the contextMenu, and adding a readonly prevent the content Editable from working (for the div used as a text area).

Comment: @DynamicRemo HTML, result and precision have been added, if you have any clue don't hesitate, I kinda reach a dead end on my side before posting here, I try to find some other way on Google, but for now I got no result

Comment: @Slayner so what you want is: uneditable menu and editable textarea like https://jsfiddle.net/2wown2cr/3/

Comment: @TonyWu what i want is not to touch the contentEditable, and to have my contextMenu to work as all contextMenu work, as per say, open with right click, show me the things inside, and permit these thing to be clickable for my next action (all of the above work except for the part where the things are clickable). The P element of my contextMenu already got the click event, but it is not working.

Comment: @Slayner have a look at my answer,, that might help you. Or simple just try with the flow of video, it will take 5mins only. All the best!

Comment: @TonyWu something like this i guess https://jsfiddle.net/2wown2cr/5/. As you can see the contextMenu is still considerated as a contentEditable, you just block it with readOnly and disable, but it prevent the javascript function to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, I find the anwser. You now IE is not like every other web browser, well if you want to do this in IE you have to use a specifique thing to attach the event. On the line where you generate the event for the context menu, you need to put :

```
p.attachEvent("onclick", alertMe);
```

with alerMe is the name of your event without "()" at the end. If you use setAttribute or addEventListener it won't work.

If you need to add some params to the event you can do this :

```
p.attachEvent("onclick", function { return myFunction(params1,params2,paramsX)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Context Menu Tag.

```
<menu type="context" id="mymenu">
    <menuitem label="Refresh Post" onclick="window.location.reload();" icon="/refresh-icon.png"></menuitem>
    <menuitem label="Skip to Comments" onclick="window.location='#comments';" icon="/comment_icon.gif"></menuitem>
    <menu label="Share on..." icon="/images/share_icon.gif">
        <menuitem label="Twitter" icon="/images/twitter_icon.gif" onclick=""></menuitem>
        <menuitem label="Facebook" icon="/images/facebook_icon16x16.gif" onclick=""></menuitem>
    </menu>
</menu>
```

Here's the reference Video, i found it on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jBRzsKrfxI)

Cheers ;)

Comment: I can't use menu tag and menuItem, it's for IE11 and the tuto you give use JQuery, as i do it in Javascript it won't work. I already Watch this video a while ago but it won't help with my case because all of the contextMenu is generated by Javascript and not hard coded in the page. The only bug i have is that my tag inside the contextMenu are considerated as text and not as element clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue (on my end anyway) came from:

`<P onclick=alertMe(); class=ctxline>viorne</P>`

"I replaced it with:

`<P onclick=alert("test"); class=ctxline>viorne</P>`

[Edit] Here's your updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2wown2cr/5/

This seems to fix the issue. If you still got any problem please specify your browser information.

Comment: Still not working, i am in IE11 and the contextMenu is generated by JS, it's still considered as a text element and so it is not clickable (it is like he don't see each element independently but only as a big text with content editable for the div).